# Does mysqli_num_rows take as much time to run as the query itself?

Tags: php, mysqli

Does  mysqli_num_rows take as much time to run as the query itself?

```
$query = Select * FROM table Where X = 'Y'

mysqli_num_rows($query)

mysqli_query($con, $query)
```

My assumption is that num rows would be faster, but how and why if it's making the same comparisons as the query?

Comment: You're misunderstanding how `mysqli_num_rows()` works. You must first execute the query, then call `mysqli_num_rows($result)` where `$result` is the mysqli result object returned by the query. So you always have to execute the query - you cannot get metadata on it without first executing it.

Comment: Have a look at the Procedural Style example in the docs to see how it is used: https://secure.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.num-rows.php

Answer (score 1):

`mysqli_num_rows()` doesn't execute any queries. You still need to execute a query/statement and only then you will have your mysqli_result object, which has this property.

`mysqli_num_rows()` doesn't do anything really. It is just reading an integer number from the object. The count of rows in the object is done when mysqli instantiates the mysqli_result object.

The fact is that this property/function is useless most of the time. To get the count of rows in the database you need to run `SELECT COUNT(*)` instead. This is definitely faster than fetching all results and counting the rows. The less data is to be send from MySQL to PHP the better.